# The relative virtual path is not allowed here C#

Tags: c#, pdf, path, .net-4.6

I'm having issues with this piece of C# code

```
var localPath = $"Images\\AgencyWatermarkPaid\\watermarkpaid{invoice.AgencyId}.png";
                string targetOutputFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +
                    localPath);
                var watermarkPath = targetOutputFile;
                iTextSharp.text.Image watermark = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(watermarkPath);
                watermark.SetAbsolutePosition(-100, 0);
                document.Add(watermark);
```

, I always get the following exception

The relative virtual path 'C:/WorkSpace/BDA/src/BDA.Services/Images/AgencyWatermarkPaid/watermarkpaid20.png' is not allowed here.

Comment: *"I always get the following exception"* - thrown by which method of which class with which stack trace?

Comment: I can't find any iTextSharp docs on line, but whenever I see GetInstance being called with a path, it's a relative path, not an absolute path.  Have you tried that?  Generally, in an ASP.NET app, a _relative virtual path_ looks something like `"~/images/someimage.jpg"` or whatever